# JavaFX: Drag and drop whole Table column into second TableView

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, tableview

I need to drag column from one TableView and drop it into another TableView. Something like reorder but between two tables. In docs there is example just for rows.

Comment: What do you want the outcome of the drop operation to be? Do you want to add a similar column to the target TableView? That would indicate that the two tables contain data of the same type, is that correct?

Comment: The result would be adding new column in target TableView which will have the same data as in the first table.